# How does this dependency injection (DI) service maintain data when it is registered as transient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, azure-web-app-service

I have been given an example application that uses a memory cache as a substitute for a Redis cache. I believe the intention was that this is supposed to be suitable for testing the application (in the absence of Redis).

The abstraction

```
public interface IJobStorageService
{
    Task WriteAsync(string databaseKey, Job job); 
    Task<Job> ReadAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId); 
    Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId); 
}
```

MemoryCacheJobStorageService

```
public sealed class MemoryCacheJobStorageService : IJobStorageService
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> jobs = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job>();
    private static string Key(string databaseKey, string jobId) =>
        $"{databaseKey}:{jobId}";

    public Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId)
    {
        Job value;
        return Task.FromResult(jobs.TryRemove(Key(databaseKey, jobId), out value));
    }
    public Task<Job> ReadAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId)
    {
        var key = Key(databaseKey, jobId);
        return jobs.ContainsKey(key) ? Task.FromResult(jobs[key]) : null;
    }
    public Task WriteAsync(string databaseKey, Job job)
    {
        jobs[Key(databaseKey, job.JobId)] = job;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

RedisCacheJobStorageService

```
public sealed class RedisCacheJobStorageService : IJobStorageService
{
    private readonly IDatabaseAsync redis;
    public RedisCacheJobStorageService(IConnectionMultiplexer redis)
    {
        this.redis = redis.GetDatabase();
    }
    public async Task WriteAsync(string databaseKey, Job job)
    {
        var data = await Task.Run(() =>
            JsonConvert.SerializeObject(job, Formatting.None));
        await redis.HashSetAsync(databaseKey, job.JobId, data);
    }
    public async Task<Job> ReadAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId)
    {
        var data = await redis.HashGetAsync(databaseKey, jobId);
        return await Task.Run(() =>
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Job>(data));
    }
    public async Task<bool> DeleteAsync(string databaseKey, string jobId)
    {
        bool rc = await redis.HashDeleteAsync(databaseKey, jobId);
        return rc;
    }
}
```

The *Startup.cs* has this...

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (useRedisCache)
        {
            // setup redis cache for horizontally scaled services
            services.AddSingleton<IConnectionMultiplexer>(
                ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisCacheConnectionString));
            // CRUD operations for jobs in the redis cache
            services.AddTransient<IJobStorageService, RedisCacheJobStorageService>();
        }
        else
        {
            // strictly for testing
            // CRUD operations for jobs in the memory cache
            services.AddTransient<IJobStorageService, MemoryCacheJobStorageService>();
        }


        services.AddControllers();
    }
}
```

How can the dictionary inside the service possibly survive given that this is a transient service?

Comment: If it's for testing, isn't it sufficient for the dictionary to last as long as the process?

Comment: @John  The Redis object has a method to match each method here. If it is "parallel" to Redis then I think it needs to be a really good substitute for Redis. I can't see how this can have a long lifetime if it is a transient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can the dictionary inside the service possibly survive given that this is a transient service?

Because the dictionary inside the service is **static**.

```
//...

private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job> jobs = 
        new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Job>();

//...
```

The first time the `MemoryCacheJobStorageService` implementation is initialized, the dictionary will be created and remain in memory. All instances of the implementation created (transient) will therefore use the same static dictionary in memory for the lifetime of the process.

Reference [**static (C# Reference)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

> Use the `static` modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the ***type*** itself rather than to a specific object.

***emphasis mine***

Comment: "Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested from the service container."  If you have a new object then you do not have the old dictionary.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Yes you do have the old dictionary. You seem to not understand how static works in c#. If a class has a static member, that member remains with the type no matter how many times you initialize or dispose of an instance.